# How to convert extension XUL to addon SDK firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I have an addon folder structure like this

```
-components
-chrome
-defaults
-modules
-chrome.manifest
-install.rdf
```

I want to convert it like this and use sdk firefox

```
-data
-lib
-test
-package.json
```

How can I do so?

Comment: It would be easier to convert to a purely bootstrapped addon rather than addon-sdk strapped addon. And the conversion is kind of case specific. You got a link to your repo? Also as you are used to XUL scoping, add-on sdk scoping will drive you nuts. So I would suggest for you to not go to add-on sdk, the scoping is totally different. BUT nice thing about add-on sdk is that it handles e10s for you. Just thoughts. You may still want addon-sdk. But I dont know really much about sdk.